# replacing date by days in large file

Tags: bash, awk

i have a large file with entries of the form

```
20|27.10.2017 19:51:35.764000|354949

20|28.10.2017 17:44:37.095000|863925

20|31.10.2017 09:00:47.578000|438836
```

the entries in the middle represent a date (european format) and a time.

i would like to replace this by the following

```
20|2|354949

20|3|863925

20|6|438836
```

and store this in a new file,
where now the entry in the middle represents the number of days between (say) oct-25-2017 and the date.

to make the question more clear:

i would like to replace the date-time entries of the form

28.10.2017 17:44:37.095000

by the number of days between 25.10.2017 and (in this example) 28.10.2017, e.g., (in this example) 3.

could anyone give me a hint on how to do this efficiently (the file has about 1500 millions of entries...)

thanks!!!

Comment: Please make the question clear as to what you like to see the end result. Don't understand how your filtering. Please give a clear example.

Comment: i tried to make it clear.

Comment: Please note that regexes are for matching string patterns.  They're not for performing arithmetic operations, and certainly not date calculations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="|"; base=mktime("2017 10 25 00 00 00")} 
             {split($2,t,"[. :]");
              secs=mktime(t[3]" "t[2]" "t[1]" "t[4]" "t[5]" "t[6])-base 
              $2=int(secs/(60*60*24))}1' file

20|2|354949    
20|3|863925
20|6|438836
```

convert date/time and the baseline to seconds, take the diff and convert to days.